# Shell script - sed doesn't work

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have:
test.txt:

```
version-1
version-1
```

ori.sh:

```
old="version-1"
new="version-2"
sed -i .bak 's/${old}/${new}/g' test.txt
```

when running ori.sh, nothing happens. I would expect that test.txt would look like:

test.txt*:

```
version-2
version-2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Single quotes is the problem. bash (or other shells) don't expand variables in single quotes.

Use this sed command with double quotes so that shell can expand variables:

```
sed -i.bak "s/${old}/${new}/g" test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to double quote out your variables.

The following works for me:

```
old="version-1"
new="version-2"
sed -i.bck 's:'"${old}"':'"${new}"':g' test.txt
```