# Bash / Regex: Replacing the second field in a CSV file when some of the first fields start with quotes and commas within those

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, csv

This question is for a code written in bash, but is really more a regex question. I have a file (`ARyy.txt`) with CSV values in them. I want to replace the second field with `NaN`. This is no problem at all for the simple cases (rows 1 and 2 in the example), but it's much more difficult for a few cases where there are quotes in the first field and they have commas in them. These quotes are literally only there to indicate there are commas within them (so if quotes are only there if commas are there and vice versa). Quotes are always the first and last characters if there are commas in the first field.

Here is what I have thus far. NOTE: please try to answer using sed and the general format. There is a way to do this using `awk` for FPAT from what I know  but I need one using `sed` ideally (or simple use case of `awk`).

```
#!/bin/bash
LN=1                                             #Line Number 
while read -r LIN                                #LIN is a variable containing the line
    do
    echo "$LN: $LIN"
    ((LN++))
    if [ $LN -eq 1 ]; then 
        continue                                 #header line
    elif [[ {$LIN:0:1} == "\"" ]]; then          #if the first character in the line is quote
        sed -i '${LN}s/\",/",NaN/' ARyy.txt      #replace quote followed by comma with quote followed by comma followed by NaN
    else                                         #if first character doesn't start with a quote
        sed -i '${LN}s/,[^,]*/,0/' ARyy.txt; fi  
done < ARyy.txt
```

Other pertinent info:
There are never double or nested quotes or anything peculiar like this
There can be more than one comma inside the quotations
I am always replacing the second field
The second field is always just a number for the input (Never words or quotes)

**Input Example:**

```
Fruit, Weight, Intensity, Key 
Apple, 10, 12, 343 
Banana, 5, 10, 323 
"Banana, green, 10 MG", 3, 14, 444               #Notice this line has commas in it but it has quotes to indicate this)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Fruit, Weight, Intensity, Key 
Apple, NaN, 12, 343
 Banana, NaN, 10, 323 
"Banana, green, 10 MG", NaN, 14, 444             #second field changed to NaN and first field remains in tact
```

Comment: You're better off using an actual CSV parser in a perl or python or whatever program.

Comment: @Shawn I don't have the option of using another CSV parser here

Comment: the 2nd, 3rd and 4th lines appear to be numbers ... is it safe to assume that the only field that might contain double quotes is the 1st field?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes that is true as well. I will add that to the description as well.

Comment: You should tell whoever's given you that stupid restriction that you need to use the proper tools for the job. They wouldn't expect you to cut a 2x4 in half with a screwdriver, would they?

Comment: Perl one-liner using the handy [`Text::AutoCSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module:  `perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new->out_map("WEIGHT" => sub { "NaN" })->write' < input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: @Shawn lol well It should be possible with sed and regex, correct? I just am not an expert with Regex.

Comment: not sure I'd want to use `sed -i` to constantly overwrite the same input file that's being processed by the parent `while` loop; the first `sed` is replacing a field with `NaN` while the 2nd `sed` is replacing a field with `0` ... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -E -i '2,$ s/^("[^"]*"|[^",]*)(, *)[0-9]*,/\1\2NaN,/' ARyy.txt
```

Explanation: `sed -E` invokes "extended" regular expression syntax, so it's easier to use parenthesized groups.

- `2,$` = On lines 2 through the end of file...
- `s/` = Replace...

  - `^` = the beginning of a line
  - `("[^"]*"|[^",]*)` = *either* a double-quoted string *or* a string that doesn't contain any double-quotes or commas
  - `(, *)` = a comma, maybe followed by some spaces
  - `[0-9]*` = a number
  - `,` = and finally a comma
- `/` = ...with...

  - `\1` = the first `()` group (i.e. the original first field)
  - `\2` = the second `()` group (i.e. comma and spaces)
  - `NaN,` = Not a number, and the following comma
- `/` = end of replacement

Note that if the first field could contain escaped double-quotes and/or escaped commas (not in double-quotes), the first pattern would have to be significantly more complex to deal with them.

BTW, the original has an antipattern I see disturbingly often: reading through a file line-by-line to decide what to do with that line, then running something that processes *the entire file* in order to change that one line. So if you have a thousand-line file, it winds up processing the entire file a thousand times (for a total of a million lines processed). This is what's known as "quadratic scaling", because it takes time proportional to the square of the problem size. As [Bruce Dawson put it](https://twitter.com/BruceDawson0xB/status/1120381406700429312),

> O(n^2) is the sweet spot of badly scaling algorithms: fast enough to make it into production, but slow enough to make things fall down once it gets there.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good answer. Later in the program, I need to change one single row's second field (which is NaN now after doing the command) to now 0 (so all entries except this row will be NaN except  this row will be 0). 

What I have is: 
while (go through file)
----Logic to identify which row to turn NaN to 0-----
sed -E -i '${LINEAV}s/^("[^"]*"|[^",]*)(, *)[0-9]*,/\1\20,/' ARyy.txt

where LINEAV is just the line number in the file.But for some reason I am getting the error sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command.Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: The only difference is I now have '${LINEAV}s ... to start it instead of '2,$ s/ ...  to start it.

Comment: Shell variables don't get substituted in single-quoted strings (see [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394248/shell-script-sed-doesnt-work)). The string contains double-quotes and backslashes, which would require special treatment (escaping) in a double-quoted string, so it's probably simplest to mix quoting modes: `sed -E -i "${LINEAV}"' s/^("[^"]*"|[^",]*)(, *)([0-9]*|NaN),/\1\20,/' ARyy.txt` (Note: I also modded it to handle the second field being "NaN").

Comment: Thank you. But when we run, for example, sed -E -i "${3}"' s/^("[^"]*"|[^",]*)(, *)[0-9]*,/\1\2YYY,/' ARyy.txt , why does this change every second entry to YYY instead of just the 3rd row? What's going on here ? I just want to change one specify row, not the entire file.

Comment: `${3}` expands to the third argument to the script (or function, if it's in one), so it'd depend on that that is. Note: I recommend putting `set -x` before a section of a script you're having trouble with, so it'll print a trace of what the command is *after* substitutions and such have been done (although note that it sometimes quotes things weirdly).

Comment: Thanks. Why did you recommend to make it sed -E -i "${LINEAV}"' s/^("[^"]*"|[^",]*)(, *)([0-9]*|NaN),/\1\20,/' ARyy.txt  then? ${LINEAV} is effectively ${3}. How would I write this line if all I want to do is change one singular line specified by a line number? In the past I've used statements like sed -i "${LINEAV}s/... and it works. But here it is giving me this  error sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra character for that version and the one you suggested is treating this separated ${3} as the input arguments. Any thoughts on what I should make this? Thank you

Comment: If the `LINEAV` variable is set to 3, `${LINEAV}` will expand to "3", *not* to the third argument. Try this: `set arg1 arg2 arg3; LINEAV=3; echo "LINEAV is ${LINEAV}, the third argument is ${3}"`. (Note: `set` sets the argument list for the current context.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234952/discussion-between-prospero-and-gordon-davisson).

Answer (score 0):

Given your specific format, in particular that the first field won't ever have any escaped double quotes in it:

```
sed -E '2,$ s/^("[^"]*"|[^,]*),[^,]*/\1,NaN/' < input.csv > output.csv
```

This does require the common but non-standard `-E` option to use POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax instead of the default Basic (which doesn't support alternation).

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat verbose) `awk` idea that replaces the entire set of code posted in the question:

```
awk -F'"' '                         # input field separator = double quotes

function print_line() {             # print array
    pfx=""
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", pfx, arr[i]
        pfx=OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
}

FNR==1 { print ; next }             # header record

NF==1  { split($0,arr,",")          # no double quotes => split line on comma
         arr[2]=" NaN"              # override arr[2] with " NaN"
       }

NF>=2  { split($3,arr,",")          # first column in from file contains double quotes
                                    # so split awk field #3 on comma; arr[2] will
                                    # be empty
         arr[1]="\"" $2 "\""        # override arr[1] with awk field #1 (the double
                                    # quoted first column from the file
         arr[2]=" NaN"              # override arr[2] " NaN"
       }
       { print_line() }             # print our array
' ARyy.txt
```

For the sample input file this generates:

```
Fruit, Weight, Intensity, Key
Apple, NaN, 12, 343
Banana, NaN, 10, 323
"Banana, green, 10 MG", NaN, 14, 444
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while read -r LIN; do
    if [ $LN -eq 1 ]; then
        ((LN++))
        continue
    elif [[ $LIN == $(echo "$LIN" | grep '"') ]]; then
        word1=$(echo "$LIN" | awk -F ',' '{print $4}')
        echo "$LIN" | sed -i "$LN"s/"$word1"/\ NaN/ ARyy2.txt

    elif [[ $LIN == $(echo "$LIN" | grep -E '[A-Z][a-z]*[,]\ [0-9]') ]]; then
        word2=$(echo "$LIN" | cut -f2 -d ',')
        echo "$LIN" | sed -i "$LN"s/"$word2"/\ NaN/ ARyy2.txt
    fi
    echo "$LN: $LIN"
    ((LN++))
done <ARyy.txt
```

make a copy of input **`ARyy.txt`** to **`ARyy2.txt`** and use this  text files as the output.
(read from `ARyy.txt` and write to `ARyy2.txt`)

- the first **elif** `$(echo "$LIN" | grep '"')` checks if the LINE starts with quotes `"` returns:
  [image]
  once selected, want to grab the number 3 with `awk -F ',' '{print $4}`and saved to variable `word1`. `-F` tells `awk` to separate columns each time encounters a `,` so 6 columns in total and number `3` is in column **4** that's why `{print $4}`

  ```sh
    echo "$LIN" | sed -i "$LN"s/"$word1"/\ NaN/ ARyy2.txt
  ```

  - then use **sed** to select line number with `$LN`. The number `3` inside variable `/$word1/`. for replacement with `/NaN/` BUT want to add a space to NaN so need to escape `\` the space with `/\ NaN/`
  - always using `echo $LIN` to grab the correct **LINE**
- the second **elif** `$(echo "$LIN" | grep -E '[A-Z][a-z]*[,]\ [0-9]')` returns:
  [image: return lines with pattern regex]

  `$LIN` only returns one line a time, like this:
  [image]
  The important is to check if the LINE has this pattern `Word` + `space` + `ONE Digit`
  once selected, want to grab the number 10[second column] this time with  `cut -f2 -d ','`  and save it to variable `word2`. `-f2` selects the second column, and `-d` is telling **cut** to use `,` to separate each column.